# Allow users to download files via SFTP, delete files, but not add or modify

Tags: linux, security, centos, sftp, centos-7

I have an SFTP server on CentOS 7.4 (through the standard `sshd`), and I want to adjust the server so that users can download files in their directory, delete files in their directory, but cannot upload new files or overwrite files.

I can use `chmod` to set `rw`, but I don't want users to be able to upload new files or modify them, just download them.

Is there any trick I can use here? (Seems like most people want to block deletions, and allow additions / modifications, I want the opposite.)

I also have SELinux enabled and functioning, if that helps as well.

The closest I've gotten is `chmod 555`, `chown` for the user, but then I can't delete the file, only read it. If I `chmod 755` to the directory, I can read and delete files, and I cannot modify existing files, but I can still add new files.

Also, appropriate portion of my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match Group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /zfspool/sftp/%s
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Everything else is default. The SFTP server is:

```
Subsystem    sftp    /user/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using blacklisting feature of sftp-server, in your sshd_config, set :

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -P write
```

or alternatively if using internal-sftp:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp -P write
```

You can control allowed requests in white/black list mode, see man sftp-server and sftp-server -Q requests to get the list of available requests on your server.

Comment: So adding that `-P write` to my `sshd_config` didn't work, does it have anything to do with the `ForceCommand internal-sftp` / `chroot`?

Comment: indeed: updated my answer to move -P write to internal-sftp directive.